# Setting up Google Sheets for Developers with node.js, after allowing my API to view my spreadshhets, it redirects to a "Page not found"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) to work with node and I've got as far that it asks me to sign it with my Google account and the allow the app to view my Google Spreadsheets. After I press allow it redirects me to a [Page not found](http://localhost:8080/?code=4/0AY0e-g58X7zKTqMxLsplnc4S2hHdk9HzEBrAgEMGuPzBgcjn5ypcc0uAWfwC4Mu3zR_aXg&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly) saying "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". In the URL it reads "code=4" but I can't find what this stands for. I'm currently stuck in my console waiting for a code from this page. [image: Waiting for code].

My code is the exact same as on the API documentation but I had to change "credentials.installed" to just "credentials" because otherwise it didn't work.

Has it maybe something to do with my callback URIs? I have both "Authorised JavaScript origins" and Authorised redirect URIs" as just "http://localhost:8080".

My credentials.JSON looks like this

```
{
"client_id":"XXXX",
"project_id":"XXXX","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_secret":"XXXX",
"redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8080"],
"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8080"]
```

}

In summary: I get a "Page not found" instead of the code that you're supposed to paste to the console after I press the "Accept" button.

Comment: Can you please your code because maybe your issue is related to the way that you are implementing the quickstart.

Comment: I'm not really implementing it at all. Just trying to get the quickstart to work first. I haven't done this before, I thought the quickstart is all I need to get it working. Only other file I have is the JSON with the OAuth ID stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I selected "web application" instead of "desktop application". Just download credentials JSON and copy code directly from quick start and it will work. My bad.